# How do I dynamically create CriteriaQuery

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteriaquery

I want to create equivalent CriteriaQuery to this query :
select u from User u where u.name = "John" and u.surname = "Black" and u.middlename = "Small";
but I have problem with "where" predicate. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery c = ...;
Root root = ...;

Predications name = builder.equal(root.get("name"), name);
Predications surname = ...;
Predications middlename = ...;

c.where(name, surname, middlename);
```